# Build SQL Select a better way ? (Oracle)

Tags: php, zend-framework, mysql

i have the following code part in one of my classes:

```
                $l = new Location();
                $result = $l->getLocIdsbyCity($city); // returns csv
                $ids = explode(',', $result);

                $where = 'LOC_ID = ' . $ids[0];
                unset($ids[0]);

                foreach ($ids as $id) {
                    $where .= ' OR LOC_ID = ' . $id;
                }

                $select->where($where);
```

Is there an more "elegant" way to build the select stmt? I need all records with one of the provided ids..

Comment: Oracle but "WHERE IN()" Works great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `csv` is injection safe (contains trusted values and no user-provided input):

```
            $l = new Location();
            $result = $l->getLocIdsbyCity($city); // returns csv
            $where = "LOC_ID IN ($result)";
            $select->where($where);
```

If it's not, you should explode it, `mysql_real_escape_string` each value and implode back.

Comment: actually he can also use 
$where = 'LOC_ID IN (?)';
$select->where($where, $result);

Comment: @Tomas: probably, I'm not an expert in `Zend` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `in` operator to form a condition like:

```
where LOC_ID in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

If you are sure that `$result` can't contain anything harmful, you should be able to use it directly without having to split it and loop.